# Rotate bitmap in fixed point like a clock hand in SurfaceView

Tags: android, bitmap, surfaceview

I have an image in `drawable` folder for clock hand. I want to rotate it in fixed point like a clock hand. I have tried below code which rotates the hand in circular path around a fixed point but not as like clock hand.

```
 Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
 matrix.reset();
 matrix.preTranslate(0, 0);
 matrix.postRotate(angleRotation, -0, -0);
 matrix.postTranslate(240, 480);

 canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
 canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
```

I am struggling for hours to get it sorted out. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have tried below links for help as well with no success.

1. [SurfaceView, draw image and reduce size, rotate image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234002/surfaceview-draw-image-and-reduce-size-rotate-image)
2. [Android: How to rotate a bitmap on a center point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166917/android-how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-on-a-center-point)
3. [How to rotate a bitmap in Android about images center smoothly without oscillatory movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399173/how-to-rotate-a-bitmap-in-android-about-images-center-smoothly-without-oscillato)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. Let `px` and `py` be any point on `canvas`. `bitmap.getWidth()/2` is middle point along bitmap width. It can be any point for `x cordinate`. For `y cordinate` I have taken it as `10`. `angleRotation` is the angle that is as per required.

So `matrix.postTranslate(-bitmap.getWidth()/2, -10);` is the **point of rotation**.

Below is the code.

```
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.reset();
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        float px = 240;
        float py = 480;
        matrix.postTranslate(-bitmap.getWidth()/2, -10);
        matrix.postRotate(angleRotation);
        matrix.postTranslate(px, py);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, paint);
```

Above code satisfy my requirements. Please modify it as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to rotate my bitmaps.

```
 private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap src,int degrees) {
         Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
         matrix.postRotate(degrees);
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```