# Changing watch hands android wear

Tags: android, wear-os, watch-face-api

I am trying to make my own watch face for android wear. I am able to set the background image and change the what hand style but how do I replace the hands completely with custom hands like the one below (Mickey mouse hand):

[image]

Comment: Assuming you are going through this: http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/drawing.html#Drawing - instead of drawLine, you are drawing a bitmap (along with the correct PorterDuff mode as appropriate)

Comment: I am trying drawBitmap. it requires the co-ordinates for a rectangle i basically want to place the image on a line. How do I do this ?

Comment: I expect you mean a rotating line - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35406924/rotate-bitmap-in-fixed-point-like-a-clock-hand-in-surfaceview